# Conditional mutate and vector

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(letters[1:3], 2)
)
```

And the following vector:

```
vec <- c(1.5, 3.2)
```

This vector belongs to each `b` in `df`. How do I mutate `vec` if it matches `b` and return `NA` values if not?

**Expected outcome:**

```
1                    a                          NA
2                    b                         1.5
3                    c                          NA
4                    a                          NA
5                    b                         3.2
6                    c                          NA
```

Comment: We are assuming length of vec(2), is always same as number of "b"s(2) in df?

Comment: yes! vec and b would always have the same length

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplest way would be to get indexes of "b" and replace them with `vec`.

```
df$output[df$x == "b"] <- vec

df
#  x output
#1 a     NA
#2 b    1.5
#3 c     NA
#4 a     NA
#5 b    3.2
#6 c     NA
```

---

Another option is with `replace`

```
df$output <- replace(df$output, df$x == "b", vec)
```

---

Forcefully, fitting this into `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)

df$output <- NA
df %>%
  mutate(output = replace(output, x == "b", vec))
```

Comment: Hadley said: "dplyr will never support in-place mutation of data" (https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/425#issuecomment-43085948) so this is not directly possible with tidyverse even though it is very simple in base R.

If you wish to fit this within a `mutate` I recommend: `df %>% mutate(output = NA, output = replace(output, x == "b", vec))`